# Can't Navigate Back to Xamaran Shell Page After First Visit

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I must not understand the concept correctly and I am doing something - though I don't get what.

I have a page ("page2") that is on the Shell/Flyout. Once on this page, for any number of reason (when it first loads, on an action, etc.) the user is redirected to "page3" that uses Shell.Current.GoToAsync("page3?id=xxxx") to go to a page that is in the global routes. That works.

If I try to go back to "page2" - using await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("///page2") "page3" gets displayed. I cannot step into anything - no OnDisappearing, OnAppearing, ctor,

What am I missing here?

Comment: You could look at the official doc abot the [Relative routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#relative-routes).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you're looking for a way to go back one page but if you are the easiest way to do so is like:

```
Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Comment: Not really. It's kind of like I went to a catalog, went to details, went to profile - and can no longer go to catalog - I get sent to details automatically.